# Difference between BubbleSort and this type sorting

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, bubble-sort

```
public class BubbleSortr {
    
    static void BubbleSorting(int[] arr){
        int steps = 0;
        int final_index = arr.length-1;
        boolean Sorted = false;
        
        while(!Sorted) {
            System.out.print("The array is: ");
            PrintArray(arr);
            System.out.println();
            Sorted = true;
            for (int i=0;i<final_index;i++) {
                steps++;
                if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]) {
                    int temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                    arr[i+1] = temp; 
                    Sorted = false;
                }
            }
            final_index-=1;
        }
        System.out.println("numbers of steps is:" + steps);
    }
    
    static void BrutalSort(int [] arr) {
        int steps =0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            System.out.print("The array is: ");
            PrintArray(arr);
            System.out.println();
            for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++) {
                steps++;
                if(arr[i]>arr[j]) {
                    int temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp; 
                }
                
            }
        }
        System.out.println("numbers of steps is:" + steps);
    }
    static void PrintArray(int[] arr) {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arr = {72,55,322,32,4,7,1,3,8,9,12,11,0};
        PrintArray(arr);
        System.out.println();
        BrutalSort(arr);
        PrintArray(arr);
    }

}
```

Hello everyone,

I am a beginner to Algorithm and Data Structure, the method I call BrutalSort is oftentimes the type of sorting function I used in my homework. Today, I just learned about BubbleSorting but I try to distinguish the difference between them, and the result is confusing to me. Does the method in the BrutalSort is the same as BubbleSort?

Comment: You should provide a reference to your "BrutalSort". Where does it come from? Is it somewhere formally defined?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the bubble sort have an early out (Sorted = true) that your sort is missing. It is also called adaptive as it can adapt to stop if it sees that no swap was done and hence everything must have been sorted by now.

Comment: Yes I just did @Surt